# Problems calling notifyDataSetChange in RecyclerViewHolder

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewholder

I am having problems updating my RecyclerView with new data. If I press a confirmation button on a CardView in the first tab, the card should get added to the second tab but it won't update it there until I rotate the screen. I get the data for the card from reading a text file. Please advise me how to call the notifyDataSetChange method after I have added the new data to my text file. I have tried everything and all I get is NullPointerExceptions. The RecyclerViews are in fragments and I use FragementStatePagerAdapter.

I'll put some of my classes here. Ask if you need more information.

*RecyclerViewAdapter.java*

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolder> {
    private List<String> mListTitle;
    private List<String> mListDesc;
    private List<String> mListPoints;
    private List<String> mListDates;
    private String fragment_tag;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter() {
    }

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<List<String>> super_list, String tag) {
        this.mListTitle = super_list.get(0);
        this.mListDesc = super_list.get(1);
        this.mListPoints = super_list.get(2);
        this.mListDates = super_list.get(3);
        fragment_tag = tag;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        return new RecyclerViewHolder(inflater, parent, fragment_tag);


    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mTitleText.setText(mListTitle.get(position));
        holder.mDescText.setText(mListDesc.get(position));
        holder.mPointsText.setText(mListPoints.get(position));
        if (fragment_tag.equals("completed")) {
            holder.mDateText.setText(mListDates.get(position));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mListTitle.size();
    }


}

class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter;
    public TextView mTitleText, mDescText, mDateText, mPointsText, popupTitle;
    public Button mConfButton, popCancelBtn, popAcceptBtn;

    public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }

    public RecyclerViewHolder(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, String tag) {
        // Inflating the card layout depending on the tag parameter.
        super(inflater.inflate
                ((tag.equals("challenges")) ? R.layout.card_view_chall : R.layout.card_view_comp, container,
                        false));
        mTitleText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_holder);
        mDescText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.desc_holder);
        mPointsText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.points_holder);
        mDateText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_holder);


        if (tag.equals("challenges")) {
            mConfButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_conf_button);

            mConfButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // Setting the layout inflater for popup window.
                    LayoutInflater pInflater = (LayoutInflater) itemView.getContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    ViewGroup container1 = (ViewGroup) pInflater.inflate(R.layout.confirmation_popup, null);
                    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(container1, 700, 600, true);

                    popupTitle = container1.findViewById(R.id.popuptext);
                    popAcceptBtn = container1.findViewById(R.id.accept_button);
                    popCancelBtn = container1.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
                    popupTitle.setText(mTitleText.getText().toString());

                    // Dismisses the popup window
                    popCancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            popupWindow.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    // Click listener for dialog accept button.
                    popAcceptBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        String date;

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                            list.add(mTitleText.getText().toString());
                            list.add(mDescText.getText().toString());
                            list.add(mPointsText.getText().toString());
                            list.add(date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date()));
                            // Saving data from current card into the completed challenges list.
                            TempDataReader reader = new TempDataReader(itemView.getContext());
                            new TempDataReader(itemView.getContext()).saveFile(list);
                            // I want to notify the dataset change here if possible!

                            popupWindow.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    popupWindow.showAtLocation(itemView, Gravity.CENTER, 25, 100);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

*SectionsPagerAdapter.java*

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();



    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title){
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();


    }
}
```

CompletedFragment.java

```
public class CompletedFragment extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
    public Fragment newInstance() {
        return new CompletedFragment();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.completed_fragment, container, false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.completed_frag);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        TempDataReader reader = new TempDataReader(getActivity());
        List<List<String>> super_list = reader.readCompFile();

        if(super_list == null || super_list.size() < 1){
            return null;
        } else{
            adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(super_list,"completed");
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

*EDIT:*
 
Added the code for the second fragment, which is the one that should be updated after the onClick at RecyclerViewHolder-class.

Comment: Can you upload a crash log?

Comment: @PratikPitale The application won't crash with this code but it won't update the data either. I am just trying to find a way to update the RecyclerView with new data.

Comment: Ok, where are you initializing an adapter?

Comment: @PratikPitale I added the code from my fragment class, I initialize my adapter there and set it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a function in your adapter for adding data:

```
public void addData(String title, String desc, String point, String date) {
    this.mListTitle.add(title);
    this.mListDesc.add(desc);
    this.mListPoints.add(point);
    this.mListDates.add(date);

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

If you want to enable animations call `notifyItemInserted()` instead of `notifyDataSetChanged();`

It is important that you add a `String` to every list because in your `onBindViewHolder()` you get the item to display from every list with `list.get(position)`. Otherwise you'll get a `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Sorry I cannot get it to work, I created that method in my RecyclerViewAdapter-class but I am having trouble calling it. I get NullPointerException if I try to call it. Here is how I tried to call it in my OnClick.    --->           
new RecyclerViewAdapter().addData(list.get(0),list.get(1),list.get(2),list.get(3));

Comment: Well when you call it that way, it is obvious that you get NPE. You have to initialize the lists once with `list = new ArrayList();` in your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an interface and use as a callback. Send it as a parameter  of the RecyclerViewAdapter and then to your RecyclerViewHolder. When the item should be added you call the callback that will get you back to your fragment. There you can read the file again and call notifyDataSetChanged.

I know i explain pretty bad so i will try to change your code so that it does what i said:

this will be your RecyclerViewAdapter:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolder> {
    private List<String> mListTitle;
    private List<String> mListDesc;
    private List<String> mListPoints;
    private List<String> mListDates;
    private String fragment_tag;

    private Runnable callback;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter() {
    }

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<List<String>> super_list, String tag, Runnable callBack) { 
//add the callback here(Runnable) and save it into a local variable

        this.callback=callback;

        this.mListTitle = super_list.get(0);
        this.mListDesc = super_list.get(1);
        this.mListPoints = super_list.get(2);
        this.mListDates = super_list.get(3);
        fragment_tag = tag;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        return new RecyclerViewHolder(inflater, parent, fragment_tag, callback);
//send the callback to your viewHolder


    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mTitleText.setText(mListTitle.get(position));
        holder.mDescText.setText(mListDesc.get(position));
        holder.mPointsText.setText(mListPoints.get(position));
        if (fragment_tag.equals("completed")) {
            holder.mDateText.setText(mListDates.get(position));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mListTitle.size();
    }


}

class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter;
    public TextView mTitleText, mDescText, mDateText, mPointsText, popupTitle;
    public Button mConfButton, popCancelBtn, popAcceptBtn;

    public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }

    public RecyclerViewHolder(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, String tag, Runnable callback) {
//ADD the callback to the parameters list here

        // Inflating the card layout depending on the tag parameter.
        super(inflater.inflate
                ((tag.equals("challenges")) ? R.layout.card_view_chall : R.layout.card_view_comp, container,
                        false));
        mTitleText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_holder);
        mDescText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.desc_holder);
        mPointsText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.points_holder);
        mDateText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_holder);


        if (tag.equals("challenges")) {
            mConfButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_conf_button);

            mConfButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // Setting the layout inflater for popup window.
                    LayoutInflater pInflater = (LayoutInflater) itemView.getContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    ViewGroup container1 = (ViewGroup) pInflater.inflate(R.layout.confirmation_popup, null);
                    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(container1, 700, 600, true);

                    popupTitle = container1.findViewById(R.id.popuptext);
                    popAcceptBtn = container1.findViewById(R.id.accept_button);
                    popCancelBtn = container1.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
                    popupTitle.setText(mTitleText.getText().toString());

                    // Dismisses the popup window
                    popCancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            popupWindow.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    // Click listener for dialog accept button.
                    popAcceptBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        String date;

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                            list.add(mTitleText.getText().toString());
                            list.add(mDescText.getText().toString());
                            list.add(mPointsText.getText().toString());
                            list.add(date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date()));
                            // Saving data from current card into the completed challenges list.
                            TempDataReader reader = new TempDataReader(itemView.getContext());
                            new TempDataReader(itemView.getContext()).saveFile(list);
                            // I want to notify the dataset change here if possible!
//call the callback
callback.run();

                            popupWindow.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    popupWindow.showAtLocation(itemView, Gravity.CENTER, 25, 100);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

And this will be your fragment:

```
public class CompletedFragment extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
    public Fragment newInstance() {
        return new CompletedFragment();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.completed_fragment, container, false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.completed_frag);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        TempDataReader reader = new TempDataReader(getActivity());
        List<List<String>> super_list = reader.readCompFile();

        if(super_list == null || super_list.size() < 1){
            return null;
        } else{
            adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(super_list,"completed", new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //here read the list again and call notifyDataSetChanged on your recycler
        }
    });
);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps and it works for you. If i did anything wrong, let me know, i can't run the code right now so...

edited, i forgot to add code in the callback